# Using attributes that don't belong (HTML)

Tags: jquery, html

Let's say I have a Table like this:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>My House </td>
<td>My Car </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

And using jquery, if you clicked on one of them, I want it to show the value of that item. Is it okay practice to store additional information in an attribute like `value` for example and then fetch it using `.attr()`

Comment: You could use `data-` attributes, or jQuery's `data()` function.

Comment: `<td data="something">Hello</td>` like this?

Comment: @SamCreamer nope, somethting like: `<td data-yourkey="something">Hello</td>`

Comment: No, like `<td data-value="something" data-id="4">Hello</td>`

Answer (score 3):

jQuery has `.data()` for applying data.  There is also the `data-xxxx` attribute for storing data while keeping your HTML valid.  Whatever method works better for you!

Answer (score 2):

As long as you have an HTML5 Doctype the page will still validate and you  can use `data-` attributes. See [jQuery data](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) and [data attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20101019/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes).

So with this markup:

```
<table id="data-table">
    <tr>
        <td data-value="house">My House </td>
        <td data-value="car">My Car </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Something like this:

```
$(function(){
    $('#data-table').on('click', 'td', function(){
        var val = $(this).data('value');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[Sure, you can do a bunch of things that way.](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/)

Comment: was unaware of `data-`'s existence, thanks

Comment: Instead a mere link, an answer should summarize the key content of the advice given.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that, although best practice is to use some specific attributes names for it like `rel` or (even better) using `data` attributes.

Example using `rel`:

```
<td rel="123">My House</td>
```

Example using `data` (more JQuery friendly):

```
<td data-value="123">My House</td>
```

For this last example, instead of retrieving the value using JQuery's `attr` function, you can use this:

```
$(elem).data("value")
```

Also to set the value you do:

```
$(elem).data("value", "new_value")
```

You can have several data attributes in the same element.

Comment: The `rel` attribute is not valid for `td` in any version of HTML.

Comment: Wow! Sorry, you are right.